# ArcPy - Syntax Error when using reclassify tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I have been writing a code to automate a variety of processes in Arc Toolbox. I have used a line to reclassify before but this time when using it I am coming up with a Parsing Error (SyntaxError). I can't see anything different to the other line where I used it apart from changing the values slightly. Could anyone have a look and shed some light of why it may not be working?

Here's my code:

```
for year in range(2008,2016):
    for month in ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']:

        #This part works
        arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa("F:/Dissertation/LAI/"+str(year)+"/s_america/"+month+"_"+str(year)+"_LAI_SA","VALUE","3 36 1;36 72 30;72 108 60;108 144 90;144 180 120;180 216 150;216 252 180;252 255 210","F:/Dissertation/LAI/"+str(year)+"/s_america/"+month+"_"+str(year)+"_LAI_REC","DATA")

        # Combine the LAI and the HYSPLIT layer. To be done in such a way that we can work out what crosses over.
        arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("""r(F:/Dissertation/LAI/"+str(year)+"/s_america/"+month+"_"+str(year)+"_LAI_REC") + r(F:/Dissertation/0201_HysplitOutputs/combined_raster/"+month+"_"+str(year)+"_RAS)""","F:/Dissertation/0201_HysplitOutputs/LAI_calc/FINAL/"+month+"_"+str(year)+"_LAI_CALC")

        # Reclassify this layer so that you have a total number of pixels that were in this category
        #This part doesn't work:
        arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa("F:/Dissertation/0201_HysplitOutputs/LAI_calc/FINAL/"+month+"_"+str(year)+"_LAI_CALC","VALUE","2 28 1;28 56 2;56 84 3;84 112 4;112 140 5;140 168 6;168 196 7;196 224 8","F:/Dissertation/0201_HysplitOutputs/LAI_calc/FINAL/"+month+"_"+str(year)"_LAI_FINAL","DATA")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `+` after `+str(year)` at the end line.

Should be:

```
arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa("F:/Dissertation/0201_HysplitOutputs/LAI_calc/FINAL/"+month+"_"+str(year)+"_LAI_CALC","VALUE","2 28 1;28 56 2;56 84 3;84 112 4;112 140 5;140 168 6;168 196 7;196 224 8","F:/Dissertation/0201_HysplitOutputs/LAI_calc/FINAL/"+month+"_"+str(year)+"_LAI_FINAL","DATA")
```

Better would be to remove your `+` and use `.format()` instead:

```
for year in range(2008,2016):
    for month in ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12']:
        #This part works
        arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa("F:/Dissertation/LAI/{2}/s_america/{0}_{1}_LAI_SA".format(month,year),"VALUE","3 36 1;36 72 30;72 108 60;108 144 90;144 180 120;180 216 150;216 252 180;252 255 210","F:/Dissertation/LAI/{1}/s_america/{0}_{1}_LAI_REC".format(month,year),"DATA")

        # Combine the LAI and the HYSPLIT layer. To be done in such a way that we can work out what crosses over.
        arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("""r("F:/Dissertation/LAI/{1}/s_america/{0}_{1}_LAI_REC") + r("F:/Dissertation/0201_HysplitOutputs/combined_raster/{0}_{1}_RAS")""".format(month,year),"F:/Dissertation/0201_HysplitOutputs/LAI_calc/FINAL/{0}_{1}_LAI_CALC".format(month,year))

        # Reclassify this layer so that you have a total number of pixels that were in this category
        #This part should now work:
        arcpy.gp.Reclassify_sa("F:/Dissertation/0201_HysplitOutputs/LAI_calc/FINAL/{0}_{1}_LAI_CALC".format(month, year),"VALUE","2 28 1;28 56 2;56 84 3;84 112 4;112 140 5;140 168 6;168 196 7;196 224 8","F:/Dissertation/0201_HysplitOutputs/LAI_calc/FINAL/{0}_{1}_LAI_FINAL".format(month,year),"DATA")
```

`.format()` to concatenate strings is far better than concatenating using `+` as it is less confusing to construct and much easier to debug when things aren't working.  [Examples for using Format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).

Comment: So I am. That would help! Will see if it work again when I come to run it. Sometimes all you need is fresh eyes!

Comment: I've just updated with a better example of how to form your strings